# How to clear instance data without setattr?

Tags: python, json, class

I wanted, to make traversable (by DB, single file or just as string) class in python. I Write this (shorted):

```
from json import JSONDecoder, JSONEncoder
def json_decode(object): return JSONDecoder().decode(object)
def json_encode(object): return JSONEncoder().encode(object)

class Storage:
__separator__ = 'ANY OF ANYS'
__keys__ = []
__vals__ = []
__slots__ = ('__keys__', '__vals__', '__separator__')

def __getattr__(self, key):
    try:
        return self.__vals__[self.__keys__.index(key)]
    except IndexError:
        raise AttributeError

def __setattr__(self, key, val):
    self.__keys__.append(key)
    self.__vals__.append(val)

def store(self):
    return (json_encode(self.__keys__) + self.__separator__ +
            json_encode(self.__vals__))

def restore(self, stored):
    stored = stored.split(self.__separator__)
    for (key, val) in zip(json_decode(stored[0]), json_decode(stored[1])):
        setattr(self, key, val)
```

And yea - that work, but... When i'm making more instances, all of them are like singleton.

**So - how to set attribute to instance without _*setattr*_?**

PS. I got idea - make in **set/getattr** an pass for **keys/vals**, but it'll make mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `__separator__`, `__keys__`, `__vals__` and `__slots__` are attributes of the object "Storage"(class object). I don't know if it's exactly the same, but I'd call it static variables of the class.

If you want to have different values for each instance of Storage, define each of these variables in your `__init__` function:

```
class Storage(object):
    __slots__ = ('__keys__', '__vals__', '__separator__')
    def __init__(self):
        super(Storage, self).__setattr__('__separator__', "ANY OF ANYS")
        super(Storage, self).__setattr__('__keys__', [])
        super(Storage, self).__setattr__('__vals__', [])

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            vals = getattr(self, '__vals__')
            keys = getattr(self, '__keys__')
            return vals[keys.index(key)]
        except IndexError:
            raise AttributeError

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        vals = getattr(self, '__vals__')
        keys = getattr(self, '__keys__')
        vals.append(val)
        keys.append(key)
```

edited so getattr and setattr works

I got that problem 2 days ago. Don't know if that's exactly your problem, but you said that about "its like I have a singleton"

Comment: __slots__ are for save memory (google it)
self.xxx will be parsed by __setattr__, so that's not that what i want.

Comment: then leave `__slots__` like it was before. But if you don't set a different `[]` to both `__keys__` and `__vals__` on each instance (like I suggested), you will be sharing the same list in all your instances

Comment: I tried. `__getattr__`. When I want to `self.__key/vals__`, i got max recurence deep error - `__getattr__` oper in `__key/vals__`.

Comment: that was because in `__init__` it was using your new __getattr__ function, I've updated the code (and tried, works for me with multiple instances). It's a little tricky but does the job.

Comment: now I understand your problem :) If it's not what you wanted (because I use the class object to inherit the __getattr__) then it's ok, I will wait here to see the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Storage` class a subclass of a special base class like this:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if '_inst_' not in vars(cls):
            cls._inst = type.__new__(cls, *args, *kwargs)
        return cls._inst

class Storage(Singleton):
    ....
```

As long as you don't override `__new__()` in your subclass, all subsequent calls to create new instances after the first will return the one first created.